# Regex to find first name label for React Testing Library (including whitespace)

Tags: regex, reactjs, tdd, whitespace, react-testing-library

I'm doing TDD with React Testing Library. You can find labeled inputs in your dom using regex like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-testing-library";
import App from "./App";

it("renders a first name input field", () => {
  const { getByLabel } = render(<App />);
  const actual = getByLabel(/username/i);
  expect(actual).toBeDefined();
});
```

My problem is that in my UI there are labels with whitespace such as "First Name", or "Birth Place". How can I find these using regex?

Comment: What's the problem with whitespace?

Comment: @estus The problem is that `/firstname/i` does not find "First Name". Through your question, I just found out though, that `/first name/i`does, though.